# In Wordpress, what is happening when we register support of a theme feature?

Tags: wordpress

When creating a wordpress theme, you must enable certain theme features in your functions.php file. For example, enabling post thumbnails.

I'd like to know, in plain language, what is happening when we register support for post thumbnails in the functions.php file.

My understanding is this: the core of Wordpress has all the code for dealing with post thumbnails, including the UI for the metabox, how the uploaded image file is handled, etc.

In a theme, when we register support of the post thumbnails theme feature, we are telling the core of wordpress "our theme would like to use this capability of yours. Please let us access the functionality."

Do I have this basically correct?

Answer (score 1):

Actually these are known as [theme features](http://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Features), is a set of features defined by theme authors that allows a theme to register support of a certain feature (that is not active by default). Theme support functions should be called in the theme's [functions.php](http://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development#Functions_File) file to work.

These are not activated in WordPress by default and these are

- [Sidebar Widgets](http://codex.wordpress.org/Widgets_API)
- [Navigation Menus](http://codex.wordpress.org/Navigation_Menus)
- [Post Formats](http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Formats)
- [Post Thumbnails](http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Thumbnails)
- [Custom Backgrounds](http://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Backgrounds)
- [Custom Headers](http://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Headers)
- [Automatic Feed Links](http://codex.wordpress.org/Automatic_Feed_Links)
- [Editor Style](http://codex.wordpress.org/Editor_Style)

To register a `theme feature` you have to use [add theme support](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_theme_support) function in your functions.php, it can also be [called from a plugin](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/23839/using-add-theme-support-inside-a-plugin) if attached to a hook.